# Jquery animate three buttons to make on off switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I need to animate three buttons to create the effect of Checkbox, the three buttons arrange as:

```
| left | center | right|
```

then if a var status is set, then the three buttons should animate to left so only the center and right buttons displayed:

```
| center | right|
```

and if a var status is not set, then the three buttons should animate to left so only the center and right buttons displayed:

```
 | left | center |
```

and if any of the two displayed buttons is clicked the var state is changed and the buttons are changed accordingly.

The effect should be similar to this bootstrap plugin:

http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/examples.html

but I need this function only for my special needs.

I started this http://www.bootply.com/qraJqgMz0D

The bootstrap code is below also:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="btn-group btn-toggle" style="white-space: nowrap;">

    <button id="left-btn" class="btn btn-primary toggler" style="float: none;display: inline-block;">Left</button>
    <button id="center-btn" class="btn btn-default toggler" style="float: none;display: inline-block;margin-left:0;margin-right:0;">Center</button>
    <button id="right-btn" class="btn btn-danger toggler" style="float: none;display: inline-block;">Right</button>

</div>


<script>  

$(document).ready(function() {

  var status = false;

  $('.toggler').on('click', function(e) {
    //$(this).toggleClass('active');
    switch_status();
    console.log('click');
  });

  function switch_status(status) {
    var left = $('#left-btn');
    var center = $('#center-btn');
    var right = $('#right-btn');
    if (status) {
      left.focus().animate({width:'toggle'},350);
    }
    else {
      left.focus().animate({width:'toggle'},350);
    }
    status = !status;
  }

  switch_status(status);

});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

how about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/vbafbz73/)?

**JQUERY**

```
var status = false;
$('.toggler').click(function(){
    var $innerDiv = $('#innerdiv');
    if(status)
        $innerDiv.animate({"marginLeft":"0"},320);
    else
        $innerDiv.animate({"marginLeft":"-80"},320);
    status = !status;
});
```

**CSS**

```
#innerdiv {
    width: 240px;
}

#outerdiv{
    width: 154px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#outerdiv button:focus{
    outline: 0;
}

#outerdiv button{
    width:75px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn-group btn-toggle" id="outerdiv" >
    <div id="innerdiv">
        <button id="left-btn" class="btn btn-primary toggler">Left</button>
        <button id="center-btn" class="btn btn-default toggler">Center</button>
        <button id="right-btn" class="btn btn-danger toggler">Right</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you change the text on buttons say "center left button" it gets clipped because you set fixed with for innerdiv and outerdiv. Is there a way to do this based on current buttons and divs width instead of using fixed css widths. Remember is bootstrap btn sizes are xs, sm, md, lg. But the idea is excellent.

Comment: I think you deserve me to open another question for my above comment, do you want this?

Comment: You can calculate in run time also. Make three buttons with same width. Then Try taking 1/3rd of the inner width and do negative margin with tat width.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bh3rdxkz/)

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var status = false;

               $('#right-btn').focus().animate({width:'toggle'},350);
  $('.toggler').on('click', function(e) {
    //$(this).toggleClass('active');
      if(status == false)
      {
          status = true;
      }
      else
      {
          status = false;
      }
    switch_status();
    console.log(status);
  });

  function switch_status(status) {
    var left = $('#left-btn');
    var center = $('#center-btn');
    var right = $('#right-btn');
    if (status) {
      left.focus().animate({width:'toggle'},350);
              right.focus().animate({width:'toggle'},350);
    }
    else {
      left.focus().animate({width:'toggle'},350);
              right.focus().animate({width:'toggle'},350);

    }
    status = !status;
  }


});
```

Comment: The right button stretches and shows not good. The left and center seems ok.